# Export map without white background

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I'm trying to save an Image in QGIS Composer by polygon borders as seen in the right figure. But when I try to save it, I get a white rectangle box around my figure as seen in the left figure. Is there a way to save the figure like the right one?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In Print Composer, in the `Element Properties` of the map, uncheck `Background`and `Frame`.
Or, if the white polygon is a layer, set the rendering style to `No Symbols`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. It works when uncheck the 'background' box, but when I export it as an image by the buttons below, It still creates the squared box. What am I doing wrong here? [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObM5m.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObM5m.jpg)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the exported image?

Answer (score 3):

You need to disable the background color from `Composition -> Page Background`

[image]

1. Click on `Change`
2. Click on `Simple Fill`
3. Choose `Fill -> Transparent fill`
4. Export your image to PNG format because it supports transparent fill.

[image]

Here is the output on Gimp:

[image]